# What type of singulatity does $f(z)=\exp\left(\dfrac{z}{1-\cos z}\right)$ has at $z=0?$

Tags: complex-analysis

What type of singulatity does  $f(z)=\exp\left(\dfrac{z}{1-\cos z}\right)$ has at $z=0?$

I'm completely clueless.

**Added:**
In $\mathbb C-\{0\},f(z)=\exp\left(\dfrac{z}{1-\cos z}\right)=\exp\left(\dfrac{z}{\dfrac{z^2}{2!}-\dfrac{z^4}{4!}+...}\right)=\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{z}{2!}-\dfrac{z^2}{4!}+...}\right)$ What's next?

Comment: What type of singularity $e^{2/z}$ has at $0$, first?

Comment: Try expanding $\cos z$ as a power series. Notice that the 1 cancels, and then a $z$ from above cancels.

Comment: @julien: $e^{2/z}$ has the laurent series representation around $0$ as $1+\dfrac{2}{z}+\dfrac{1}{2!}(\dfrac{2}{z})^2+..$ So $e^{2/z}$ has an essensial singularity at $z=0.$

Comment: @proximal: Calulation added. What's next?

Comment: Yes, that was a good warm-up. Now study $g(z)=z/(1-\cos z)$ to see that it behaves like $2/z$ near $0$. Next, show that $z^n f(z)$ is unbounded on every neighborhood of $0$ for all $n\geq 0$. This characterizes essential singularity.

Comment: Maybe there is a shorter way, but I can't see how to compute the Laurent series of $f$ easily to show that it has infinitely many nonzero negative coeffciients. For the approach I suggested, consider points $z_k=1/k$, so that $z_k^n=\exp(-n\log k)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{x}{1-\cos x}=+\infty \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{x}{1-\cos x}=-\infty.$$

Hence $\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x) =0$. This shows that $f$ can't be bounded near $0$ and that $|f|$ can't tend to $\infty$ as $z\to 0$. Consequently, the singularity is neither removable nor a pole, so that leaves only an essential singularity. (Check that the singularity is indeed *isolated*.)